# How can I have 2 different styles for 2 media queries while both are the same max width but 1 has a max height

Tags: html, css

Hey Guys I Was setting a media query with a max width of 715px. I only wanted to change the background position of the header because the background image wasn't centered. So I moved it `background-position: -300px;` but now when I switch to the galaxy S5 for example the screen width is 640px so it will catch the styles from the 715px query, but the height is 360px so the image goes halfway off the screen. I thought I could fix this using

```
`@media screen and (max-width: 640px) , screen and (max-height: 360px) { 
  header { 
    background-position: 0px;
  }
 }`
```

and set the image position back to normal just when it has that width plus the height, this doesn't work though? Any ideas?

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0;
}

/*---HEADER---*/

header {
 background-image: url(https://www.pymnts.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/construction-late-payments.jpg);
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 65vh;
}

.careers-wrapper{
 width: 100%;
 height: 65vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

header h1 {
 color: white;
 font-size: 5rem;
 font-family: 'Arvo';
 margin: 0;
}

/*---NAV---*/

nav {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px grey;
}

li a {
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102,0.75);
}

ul {
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.55rem;
 margin-right: 20px;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
}

li a:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #1a1a1a;
 transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.after:after {
 position: relative;
 left: 12px;
 top: 2px;
 display: inline-block;
 content: "";
 width: 1px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102,0.25);
}

.logo {
 color: red;
 font-size: 3.7rem;
 margin: 10px;
 opacity: 1;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

/*---FORM---*/

form {
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.15);
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.form h2 {
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);
 font-size: 3rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form h2:after {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.form h2:before {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.form .row {
 margin: 20px;
 display: flex;
}

label {
 color: black;
}

label, input {
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
}

.label {
 background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.3);
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.middle {
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-right: 15px;
}

.row-1 input, .row-3 input {
 flex-basis: 33.33%;
}

.row-2 input {
 width: 100%;
}

.row-4 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-4 input, .row-4 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-5  {
 flex-direction: column;
}

.radio {
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.row-6 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-6 input, .row-6 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-7 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-7 .col {
 flex-basis: 50%;
}

.row-8 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-8 .col {
 flex-basis: 50%;
}

.crime-textarea {
 margin-top: 10px;
 display: none;
 resize: none;
}

#crime-yes:checked ~ textarea {
 display: block;
}

.row-9 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-9 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-9 input {
 margin-left: 15px;
 flex-grow: 1;
}

.row-10 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-10 input, .row-10 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-11 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-11 input, .row-11 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-12 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-12 input, .row-12 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-13  {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-13 input, .row-13 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

h3 {
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 text-align: center;
}

/*---TABLE---*/

table {
 width: 95%;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 border-spacing: 15px;
}

thead tr {
 background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.3);
 color: black;
}

thead th {
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani'; 
}

th td {
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

tbody input {
 width: 100%;
}

#submit {
 background-color: red;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 padding: 7px;
 width: 35%;
 align-self: center;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 display: block;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#submit:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #cc0000;
}

/*---FOOTER---*/

.footer .wrapper {
 display: flex;
}

.footer div {
 display: inline-block;
 flex-basis: 33.33%;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.footer h1 {
 font-size: 2rem;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.footer .inner {
 margin-left: 55px;
}

.social .inner {
 margin-left: 45px;
}

.contact .inner {
 margin-left: 35px;
}

.footer .inner:before {
 display: inline-block;
 content: '';
 width: 27.1%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 54px;
}

.footer h1 span {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

.footer h1 span:after {
    content: '';
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.wrap:before {
 content: '';
 width: 100px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 55px;
}

.links a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
 transition: color 0.4s ease;
}

.links a:hover {
 color: red;
}

.contact p {
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
}

.social i {
 font-size: 1.7rem;
 margin-right: 5px;
 position: relative;
 top: -20px;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.social i:hover {
 color: red;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#msg {
 margin-top: -15px;
}

.footer-textarea {
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.2);
 outline: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 resize: none;
 width: 89%;
}

.footer button {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 9.5%;
 margin-top: -17px;
 border: none;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 transition: all ease 0.4s;
 outline: none;
}

button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: red;
}

.dark {
 color: red;
}

.copyright {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
}



/*-------MEDIA QUERIES-------*/



/*---LAPTOP-LARGE---*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) {

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 16.5%;
 }

}


/*---TABLET-LARGE---*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 .logo {
  font-size: 5rem;
 }

 nav li {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header {
  background-position: -700px;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/
 
 .footer .inner {
  margin-left: 30px;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 88%;
 }

 .footer button {
  margin-right: 10.25%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 823px) {
 
 /*---MAIN---*/

 header, .careers-wrapper {
  height: 65vh;
 }

 .label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 812px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 nav li {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
 }

 .logo {
  font-size: 2.7rem;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header, .careers-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
 }

 label {
  font-size: 1rem;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 8.5%;
 }

 .contact .inner {
  margin-right: 20px;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 nav li {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
 }

 .logo {
  font-size: 3rem;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header {
  background-position: -600px;
 }

 header, .careers-wrapper {
  height: 65vh;
 }

 .row-1 input, .row-2 input, .row-3 input {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 7.4%;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 731px) {

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header {
  background-position: 0px;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 6%;
 }

 .contact .inner p {
  margin: 5px;
 }

}

/*------LANDSCAPE-MODE-MOBILE------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 715px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 nav ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }

 nav li {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
 }

 nav .logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header, .careers-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
 }

 header {
  background-position: -300px;
 }

 form {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
 }

 .row {
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .middle {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .row-1 input, .row-3 input {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px; 
 }

 .row-4 input, .row-6 input {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
 }

 .row-9 input {
  margin-left: 0;
 }

 #submit {
  width: 90%;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/
 
 .links a {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  top: -13px;
 }

 .contact .inner {
  margin-right: 15px;
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  width: 90.5%;
 }

 .footer button {
  margin-top: -18px;
  margin-right: 7%;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) , screen and (max-height: 360px) {
 header {
  background-position: 0px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 586px) {

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
 }

 

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .footer div {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .footer .inner {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer .inner:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 100vw;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 48px;
 }

 .footer h1 span:after {
   content: '';
   height: 2px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 1px;
   left: 0;
 }

 .social .inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
 }

 .links a {
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .social h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 #msg {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 25.5%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 80px;
 }

 .footer button {
  right: 9.25%;
  margin-top: 0.2px;
 }

 .social i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 88.5%;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .copyright {
  background-color: red;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .copyright span {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Careers | Kane Concrete & Construction LLC</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/careers.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Bitter|Lato|Montserrat|Noto+Sans|Open+Sans|Poppins|Roboto|Sarabun|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Asap|Krub|Oxygen|Rajdhani|Staatliches|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="careers-wrapper">
   <nav>
    <div class="logo">
     <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
     <div class="ham-menu">
      <div class="m1" id="m1"></div>
      <div class="m2" id="m2"></div>
      <div class="m3" id="m3"></div>
     </div>
     <ul>
      <li class="after"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html#services">Services</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>

   <h1>Join Our Team</h1>
  </div> 
 </header>

 <section class="form">
 <h2>We're Hiring</h2>

  <form action="" method="" id="form">
   <h3>General Information</h3>
   <div class="row row-1">
    <input type="text" name="First" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="Last" placeholder="Last Name" class="middle">
    <input type="text" name="SSN" placeholder="SSN">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-2">
    <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Address">
   </div>
   
   <div class="row row-3">
    <input type="text" name="City" placeholder="City">
    <input type="text" name="State" placeholder="State" class="middle">
    <input type="text" name="Zipcode" placeholder="Zipcode">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-4">
    <div class="label"><label for="Primary-Phone" class="row-4">Primary-Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="Primary-Phone" placeholder="(xxx)-xxx-xxxx">
    <div class="label"><label for="Cell-Phone" class="row-4">Cell-Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="Cell-Phone" placeholder="(xxx)-xxx-xxxx">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-5">
    <label>Are you 18 years old or older?</label>
    <div class="radio">
     <input type="radio" name="ageYears" value="Yes" id="ageYearsYes">
     <label for="ageYearsYes">Yes</label>
     <input type="radio" name="ageYears" value="No" required="" id="ageYearsNo">
     <label for="ageYearsNo">No</label>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row row-6">
    <div class="label"><label>Desired Wage:</label></div>
    <input type="text" id="wage-desired">
    <div class="label"><label>Available Start Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" id="start-date">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-7">
    <div class="col">
     <label>Are you legally authorized to work in the U.S?</label>
     <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="legally" value="Yes" id="legally-yes">
      <label for="legally-yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="legally" value="No" required="" id="legally-no">
      <label for="legally-no">No</label>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
     <label>Are you willing to submit to a drug test?</label>
     <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="drug-test" value="Yes" id="drug-yes">
      <label for="drug-yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="drug-test" value="No" required="" id="drug-no">
      <label for="drug-no">No</label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row row-8">
    <div class="col">
     <label>Have you ever been convicted of a crime? If yes, please explain.</label>
     <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="crime-answer" value="Yes" id="crime-yes">
      <label for="crime-yes" id="crime-yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="crime-answer" value="No" required="" id="crime-no">
      <label for="crime-no">No</label>
      <textarea name="crime-info" cols="70" rows="4" class="crime-textarea"></textarea>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
     <label class="">How did you hear about this job?</label>
     <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="friend" value="friend" id="friend">
      <label for="friend">friend</label>
      <input type="radio" name="friend" value="online" id="online">
      <label for="friend">online</label>
      <input type="radio" name="friend" value="other" id="other">
      <label for="other">other</label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <hr>
   <h3>Employment History</h3>

   <div class="row row-9">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer">Current/Recent Employer:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-10">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-phone">Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-phone">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-address">Address:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-address">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-11">
    <div class="label"><label for="hire-date">Hired Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="hire-date">
    <div class="label"><label for="end-date">End Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="end-date">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-12">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-title">Job Title:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-title">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-responsibilities">Job Responsibilities:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-responsibilities">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-13">
    <div class="label"><label for="wage-rate">Wage Rate:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="wage-rate">
    <div class="label"><label for="reason-left">Reason For Leaving:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="reason-left">
   </div>

   <hr>

   <div class="row row-9">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer">Current/Recent Employer:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-10">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-phone">Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-phone">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-address">Address:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-address">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-11">
    <div class="label"><label for="hire-date">Hired Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="hire-date">
    <div class="label"><label for="end-date">End Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="end-date">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-12">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-title">Job Title:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-title">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-responsibilities">Job Responsibilities:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-responsibilities">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-13">
    <div class="label"><label for="wage-rate">Wage Rate:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="wage-rate">
    <div class="label"><label for="reason-left">Reason For Leaving:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="reason-left">
   </div>

   <hr>

   <div class="row row-9">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer">Current/Recent Employer:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-10">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-phone">Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-phone">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-address">Address:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-address">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-11">
    <div class="label"><label for="hire-date">Hired Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="hire-date">
    <div class="label"><label for="end-date">End Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="end-date">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-12">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-title">Job Title:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-title">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-responsibilities">Job Responsibilities:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-responsibilities">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-13">
    <div class="label"><label for="wage-rate">Wage Rate:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="wage-rate">
    <div class="label"><label for="reason-left">Reason For Leaving:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="reason-left">
   </div>

   <hr>

   <h3>Refrences</h3>

   <div class="table-wrap">
    <table>
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>NAME</th>
       <th>RELATIONSHIP</th>
       <th>COMPANY</th>
       <th>PHONE NUMBER</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refName1" name="refName1" placeholder="John Doe" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refRel1" name="refRel1" placeholder="Relationship" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refComp1" name="refComp1" placeholder="Company Name" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refPhone1" name="refPhone1" placeholder="Phone #">
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refName1" name="refName1" placeholder="John Doe" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refRel1" name="refRel1" placeholder="Relationship" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refComp1" name="refComp1" placeholder="Company Name" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refPhone1" name="refPhone1" placeholder="Phone #">
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refName1" name="refName1" placeholder="John Doe" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refRel1" name="refRel1" placeholder="Relationship" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refComp1" name="refComp1" placeholder="Company Name" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refPhone1" name="refPhone1" placeholder="Phone #">
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refName1" name="refName1" placeholder="John Doe" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refRel1" name="refRel1" placeholder="Relationship" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refComp1" name="refComp1" placeholder="Company Name" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refPhone1" name="refPhone1" placeholder="Phone #">
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
  </form>
 </section>

 <section class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="links">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1><span>Quick Links</span></h1>

     <a href="index.html">Home</a>
     <a href="about.html">About</a>
     <a href="about.html#services">Services</a>
     <a href="careers.html">Careers</a>
     <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
     <a href="contact.html#quote">Quote</a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="social">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1><span>Social</span></h1>

     <i class="fab fa-linkedin"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-facebook"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>

     <button name="msg">Send</button>
     <textarea name="msg" class="footer-textarea" cols="45" rows="5" placeholder="Send us some feedback..."></textarea>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="contact">
    <div class="inner" class="wrap">
     <h1><span>Contact</span></h1>

     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Matt</span></p>
     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Keegan</span></p>
     <p><span class="dark">Address</span> - P.O. Box 50860 IF, ID 83405</p>
     <p><span class="dark">Email</span> - KaneConcrete@fake.com</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="copyright"><span>&copy; 2019 - Kane Concrete & Construction | ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</span></div>
 </section>
 <script src="../script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We don't want all your code. We only want the relevant code that will help us solve your problem. Please see [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Try `@media screen and (max-width: 640px and max-height: 360px)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add both media query using this css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) and (min-height: 320px) {
    header {
        background-position: 0px;
    }
}
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0;
}

/*---HEADER---*/

header {
 background-image: url(https://www.pymnts.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/construction-late-payments.jpg);
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 height: 65vh;
}

.careers-wrapper{
 width: 100%;
 height: 65vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

header h1 {
 color: white;
 font-size: 5rem;
 font-family: 'Arvo';
 margin: 0;
}

/*---NAV---*/

nav {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px grey;
}

li a {
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102,0.75);
}

ul {
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.55rem;
 margin-right: 20px;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
}

li a:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #1a1a1a;
 transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.after:after {
 position: relative;
 left: 12px;
 top: 2px;
 display: inline-block;
 content: "";
 width: 1px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102,0.25);
}

.logo {
 color: red;
 font-size: 3.7rem;
 margin: 10px;
 opacity: 1;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

/*---FORM---*/

form {
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.15);
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.form h2 {
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);
 font-size: 3rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form h2:after {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.form h2:before {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.form .row {
 margin: 20px;
 display: flex;
}

label {
 color: black;
}

label, input {
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
}

.label {
 background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.3);
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.middle {
 margin-left: 15px;
 margin-right: 15px;
}

.row-1 input, .row-3 input {
 flex-basis: 33.33%;
}

.row-2 input {
 width: 100%;
}

.row-4 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-4 input, .row-4 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-5  {
 flex-direction: column;
}

.radio {
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.row-6 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-6 input, .row-6 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-7 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-7 .col {
 flex-basis: 50%;
}

.row-8 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-8 .col {
 flex-basis: 50%;
}

.crime-textarea {
 margin-top: 10px;
 display: none;
 resize: none;
}

#crime-yes:checked ~ textarea {
 display: block;
}

.row-9 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-9 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-9 input {
 margin-left: 15px;
 flex-grow: 1;
}

.row-10 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-10 input, .row-10 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-11 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-11 input, .row-11 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-12 {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-12 input, .row-12 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

.row-13  {
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row-13 input, .row-13 .label {
 flex-basis: 24%;
}

h3 {
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 text-align: center;
}

/*---TABLE---*/

table {
 width: 95%;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 border-spacing: 15px;
}

thead tr {
 background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.3);
 color: black;
}

thead th {
 font-size: 1.3rem;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani'; 
}

th td {
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

tbody input {
 width: 100%;
}

#submit {
 background-color: red;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 padding: 7px;
 width: 35%;
 align-self: center;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 display: block;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#submit:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #cc0000;
}

/*---FOOTER---*/

.footer .wrapper {
 display: flex;
}

.footer div {
 display: inline-block;
 flex-basis: 33.33%;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.footer h1 {
 font-size: 2rem;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.footer .inner {
 margin-left: 55px;
}

.social .inner {
 margin-left: 45px;
}

.contact .inner {
 margin-left: 35px;
}

.footer .inner:before {
 display: inline-block;
 content: '';
 width: 27.1%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 54px;
}

.footer h1 span {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

.footer h1 span:after {
    content: '';
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.wrap:before {
 content: '';
 width: 100px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 55px;
}

.links a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
 transition: color 0.4s ease;
}

.links a:hover {
 color: red;
}

.contact p {
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
}

.social i {
 font-size: 1.7rem;
 margin-right: 5px;
 position: relative;
 top: -20px;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.social i:hover {
 color: red;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#msg {
 margin-top: -15px;
}

.footer-textarea {
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.2);
 outline: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 resize: none;
 width: 89%;
}

.footer button {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 9.5%;
 margin-top: -17px;
 border: none;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 transition: all ease 0.4s;
 outline: none;
}

button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: red;
}

.dark {
 color: red;
}

.copyright {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
}



/*-------MEDIA QUERIES-------*/



/*---LAPTOP-LARGE---*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) {

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 16.5%;
 }

}


/*---TABLET-LARGE---*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 .logo {
  font-size: 5rem;
 }

 nav li {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header {
  background-position: -700px;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/
 
 .footer .inner {
  margin-left: 30px;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 88%;
 }

 .footer button {
  margin-right: 10.25%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 823px) {
 
 /*---MAIN---*/

 header, .careers-wrapper {
  height: 65vh;
 }

 .label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 812px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 nav li {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
 }

 .logo {
  font-size: 2.7rem;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header, .careers-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
 }

 label {
  font-size: 1rem;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 8.5%;
 }

 .contact .inner {
  margin-right: 20px;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 nav li {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
 }

 .logo {
  font-size: 3rem;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header {
  background-position: -600px;
 }

 header, .careers-wrapper {
  height: 65vh;
 }

 .row-1 input, .row-2 input, .row-3 input {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 7.4%;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 731px) {

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header {
  background-position: 0px;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 6%;
 }

 .contact .inner p {
  margin: 5px;
 }

}

/*------LANDSCAPE-MODE-MOBILE------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 715px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 nav ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }

 nav li {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
 }

 nav .logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header, .careers-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
 }

 header {
  background-position: -300px;
 }

 form {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
 }

 .row {
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .middle {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .row-1 input, .row-3 input {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px; 
 }

 .row-4 input, .row-6 input {
  margin-bottom: 7px;
 }

 .row-9 input {
  margin-left: 0;
 }

 #submit {
  width: 90%;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/
 
 .links a {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  top: -13px;
 }

 .contact .inner {
  margin-right: 15px;
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  width: 90.5%;
 }

 .footer button {
  margin-top: -18px;
  margin-right: 7%;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) and (min-height: 320px) {
 header {
  background-position: 0px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 586px) {

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
 }

 

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .footer div {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .footer .inner {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer .inner:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 100vw;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 48px;
 }

 .footer h1 span:after {
   content: '';
   height: 2px;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: red;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 1px;
   left: 0;
 }

 .social .inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
 }

 .links a {
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .social h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 #msg {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 25.5%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 80px;
 }

 .footer button {
  right: 9.25%;
  margin-top: 0.2px;
 }

 .social i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 88.5%;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .copyright {
  background-color: red;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .copyright span {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
 }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Careers | Kane Concrete & Construction LLC</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/careers.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Bitter|Lato|Montserrat|Noto+Sans|Open+Sans|Poppins|Roboto|Sarabun|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Asap|Krub|Oxygen|Rajdhani|Staatliches|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="careers-wrapper">
   <nav>
    <div class="logo">
     <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
     <div class="ham-menu">
      <div class="m1" id="m1"></div>
      <div class="m2" id="m2"></div>
      <div class="m3" id="m3"></div>
     </div>
     <ul>
      <li class="after"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html#services">Services</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>

   <h1>Join Our Team</h1>
  </div> 
 </header>

 <section class="form">
 <h2>We're Hiring</h2>

  <form action="" method="" id="form">
   <h3>General Information</h3>
   <div class="row row-1">
    <input type="text" name="First" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="Last" placeholder="Last Name" class="middle">
    <input type="text" name="SSN" placeholder="SSN">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-2">
    <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Address">
   </div>
   
   <div class="row row-3">
    <input type="text" name="City" placeholder="City">
    <input type="text" name="State" placeholder="State" class="middle">
    <input type="text" name="Zipcode" placeholder="Zipcode">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-4">
    <div class="label"><label for="Primary-Phone" class="row-4">Primary-Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="Primary-Phone" placeholder="(xxx)-xxx-xxxx">
    <div class="label"><label for="Cell-Phone" class="row-4">Cell-Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="Cell-Phone" placeholder="(xxx)-xxx-xxxx">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-5">
    <label>Are you 18 years old or older?</label>
    <div class="radio">
     <input type="radio" name="ageYears" value="Yes" id="ageYearsYes">
     <label for="ageYearsYes">Yes</label>
     <input type="radio" name="ageYears" value="No" required="" id="ageYearsNo">
     <label for="ageYearsNo">No</label>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row row-6">
    <div class="label"><label>Desired Wage:</label></div>
    <input type="text" id="wage-desired">
    <div class="label"><label>Available Start Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" id="start-date">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-7">
    <div class="col">
     <label>Are you legally authorized to work in the U.S?</label>
     <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="legally" value="Yes" id="legally-yes">
      <label for="legally-yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="legally" value="No" required="" id="legally-no">
      <label for="legally-no">No</label>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
     <label>Are you willing to submit to a drug test?</label>
     <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="drug-test" value="Yes" id="drug-yes">
      <label for="drug-yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="drug-test" value="No" required="" id="drug-no">
      <label for="drug-no">No</label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row row-8">
    <div class="col">
     <label>Have you ever been convicted of a crime? If yes, please explain.</label>
     <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="crime-answer" value="Yes" id="crime-yes">
      <label for="crime-yes" id="crime-yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="crime-answer" value="No" required="" id="crime-no">
      <label for="crime-no">No</label>
      <textarea name="crime-info" cols="70" rows="4" class="crime-textarea"></textarea>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
     <label class="">How did you hear about this job?</label>
     <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="friend" value="friend" id="friend">
      <label for="friend">friend</label>
      <input type="radio" name="friend" value="online" id="online">
      <label for="friend">online</label>
      <input type="radio" name="friend" value="other" id="other">
      <label for="other">other</label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <hr>
   <h3>Employment History</h3>

   <div class="row row-9">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer">Current/Recent Employer:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-10">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-phone">Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-phone">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-address">Address:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-address">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-11">
    <div class="label"><label for="hire-date">Hired Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="hire-date">
    <div class="label"><label for="end-date">End Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="end-date">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-12">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-title">Job Title:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-title">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-responsibilities">Job Responsibilities:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-responsibilities">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-13">
    <div class="label"><label for="wage-rate">Wage Rate:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="wage-rate">
    <div class="label"><label for="reason-left">Reason For Leaving:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="reason-left">
   </div>

   <hr>

   <div class="row row-9">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer">Current/Recent Employer:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-10">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-phone">Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-phone">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-address">Address:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-address">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-11">
    <div class="label"><label for="hire-date">Hired Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="hire-date">
    <div class="label"><label for="end-date">End Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="end-date">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-12">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-title">Job Title:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-title">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-responsibilities">Job Responsibilities:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-responsibilities">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-13">
    <div class="label"><label for="wage-rate">Wage Rate:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="wage-rate">
    <div class="label"><label for="reason-left">Reason For Leaving:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="reason-left">
   </div>

   <hr>

   <div class="row row-9">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer">Current/Recent Employer:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-10">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-phone">Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-phone">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-address">Address:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-address">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-11">
    <div class="label"><label for="hire-date">Hired Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="hire-date">
    <div class="label"><label for="end-date">End Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="end-date">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-12">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-title">Job Title:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-title">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-responsibilities">Job Responsibilities:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-responsibilities">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-13">
    <div class="label"><label for="wage-rate">Wage Rate:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="wage-rate">
    <div class="label"><label for="reason-left">Reason For Leaving:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="reason-left">
   </div>

   <hr>

   <h3>Refrences</h3>

   <div class="table-wrap">
    <table>
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>NAME</th>
       <th>RELATIONSHIP</th>
       <th>COMPANY</th>
       <th>PHONE NUMBER</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refName1" name="refName1" placeholder="John Doe" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refRel1" name="refRel1" placeholder="Relationship" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refComp1" name="refComp1" placeholder="Company Name" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refPhone1" name="refPhone1" placeholder="Phone #">
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refName1" name="refName1" placeholder="John Doe" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refRel1" name="refRel1" placeholder="Relationship" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refComp1" name="refComp1" placeholder="Company Name" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refPhone1" name="refPhone1" placeholder="Phone #">
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refName1" name="refName1" placeholder="John Doe" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refRel1" name="refRel1" placeholder="Relationship" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refComp1" name="refComp1" placeholder="Company Name" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refPhone1" name="refPhone1" placeholder="Phone #">
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refName1" name="refName1" placeholder="John Doe" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refRel1" name="refRel1" placeholder="Relationship" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refComp1" name="refComp1" placeholder="Company Name" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refPhone1" name="refPhone1" placeholder="Phone #">
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
  </form>
 </section>

 <section class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="links">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1><span>Quick Links</span></h1>

     <a href="index.html">Home</a>
     <a href="about.html">About</a>
     <a href="about.html#services">Services</a>
     <a href="careers.html">Careers</a>
     <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
     <a href="contact.html#quote">Quote</a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="social">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1><span>Social</span></h1>

     <i class="fab fa-linkedin"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-facebook"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>

     <button name="msg">Send</button>
     <textarea name="msg" class="footer-textarea" cols="45" rows="5" placeholder="Send us some feedback..."></textarea>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="contact">
    <div class="inner" class="wrap">
     <h1><span>Contact</span></h1>

     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Matt</span></p>
     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Keegan</span></p>
     <p><span class="dark">Address</span> - P.O. Box 50860 IF, ID 83405</p>
     <p><span class="dark">Email</span> - KaneConcrete@fake.com</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="copyright"><span>&copy; 2019 - Kane Concrete & Construction | ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</span></div>
 </section>
 <script src="../script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth to add a class to your element with a jquery function then you can call the -300px only on the element that doesn not have the class (not the GalaxyS7)

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Though, I think it is better to create media queries with 'min-width' instead of 'max-width' ensuring compatibility on smaller screens.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp